# Googleのスクリプトがサーバーエラーとなる

Tags: google-apps-script

[状況]
先週辺りより、今まで使用出来ていたスクリプトが突然、スプレットシートを開いてもメニュー表示されなくなりました。
[エラー内容]
スクリプトエディタを開き、対象のスクリプトを実行させると「サーバーエラーが発生しました。しばらくしてからもう一度試してください。」のメッセージが表示されます。
[スクリプトの目的]
事業所単位でアンケート機能を使い、打刻情報をスプレットシートに書き込んでいますが、その後の処理として数式をコピーする機能のスクリプトです。
[スクリプト内容]

```
function onOpen(e){

    var arr = [
        {name: "数式コピー", functionName: "copy"}

    ];
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  　spreadsheet.addMenu("管理者メニュー", arr);
}

function copy(){
  var objSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = objSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("元データ（編集用）");
  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange('F2:S2');
  var targetToCopy = sheet.getRange('F3:S');
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(targetToCopy);
}
```

自分で作成したスクリプトではなく前任者より引き継いだものであり、スクリプト経験もないので原因追及にも及んでいません。
以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 前任者から引き継いだ時に編集者など変更されていますか？スクリプトに問題なさそうなので権限周りだと思うのですが……

Comment: 返答、ありがとうございます。
GoogleAppsに関してはほとんど知識がなく、権限移譲だけしている状態です。
編集者の変更が必要なんですか。全く知りませんでした。
編集者を変更はしていません。また、どのように行うのかご教授願えたら幸いです。

Comment: 既存スプレットに新規でプロジェクトを追加し、そこにコードをコピペしたところ、実行できました。新たなプロジェクトは私の権限になっているのでしょうね。
無事、対応出来ました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決したようでよかったです。情報が出そろっていたのにクローズされてしまった理由は分かりませんが、再オープンされましたので、解決した内容をご自身で解答しソレを承認してください。そうすれば同じ疑問を持った方への助けにもなりますので……

Answer (score 2):

コメントより

> 既存スプレットに新規でプロジェクトを追加し、そこにコードをコピペしたところ、実行できました。新たなプロジェクトは私の権限‌​になっているのでしょうね。 無事、対応出来ました。ありがとうございました。 – [user13569](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/13569/user13569) [15年12月10日 1:58](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19745/google%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B?rq=1#comment18511_19745)