# 前任者から引き継いだGoogle Apps Scriptが権限エラー？で動作しない

Tags: google-apps-script

お世話になります。
前任者から引き継いだスクリプトが動作せず、わからないながらも実行のデバックを行ったところ、

> Authorization required Untitled project needs your permission to access your data on Google

と表示され【許可】をクリックしたところ、

> 401. That’s an error.Error: deleted_client　The OAuth client was deleted.

と表示されてしまいます。

作成者のGoogleアカウントは既に削除されております。
ここから動作するにはどのような変更作業が必要でしょうか？

以下対象のコードになります。それぞれの定義名は別のgsファイルで定義されておりましたが、
退職者のアカウントに関する記述は見当たりませんでした。

```
// * ファイルオープン時の処理
// * シートの最下行を選択する。
// * （毎回一番下までスクロールするのが面倒くさいため・・）
// */
function onOpen() {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()!=SHEET_NAME_INQUIRY){
    return;
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setActiveSelection("B" + getLastRow("B")); 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("カーソルを最下行に移動しました");
}
//
///**
// * 最下行の取得
// * column：列名
// */
function getLastRow(column) {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + "1:" + column + lastRow).getValues();

  for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
  return lastRow;
}
```

Comment: 重複候補: [Googleのスクリプトがサーバーエラーとなる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/19745/3060)

Answer (score 1):

もっとも手軽なのは、そのスプレッドシートをコピーして運用する事です。スプレッドシートはそれぞれGCPのプロジェクトと連結されているので、担当者のアカウントを削除してしまうと切れてしまい、このエラーがでます。

あくまでそのスプレッドシートじゃないと駄目という事であれば、改めてプロジェクトをGCP側に作成して手動で連結すると動くようになります。結構手順があるので大変ですが頑張って下さい。

連結手順
https://00m.in/Symh7

Comment: ありがとうございます。スプレッドシートとその中にあるスクリプトも含めて新規プロジェクトで作成しました。

Comment: それでもエラーが出る為、そちらについては改めて質問経てるようにいたします。